# Missing } inserted and missing $ inserted using amsmath package

Tags: amsmath, texmaker

I'm using Texmaker 4.5 over Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to compile some amsmath code:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
$\underset{\mathbf{S}}{\operatorname{arg\,min}}$ 
  \displaystyle\sum\_{i=1}^{k} \sum\_{\mathbf x \in S\_i}
  \left\| \mathbf x - \boldsymbol\mu\_i \right\|^2
\end{eqnarray*}
```

When compiling, got both `Missing } inserted` and `missing $ inserted` in the line that begins with `$\underset`....

I guess I've escaped correctly all needed escapes; been trying to fix it for some minutes now with no success, wanted to check with someone more proficient at this.

Thank you for your collaboration!

Comment: `eqnarray` is already math so you do not want `$` (or `\displaystyle`) but it is usually better to avoid `eqnarray` and use `align` from the amsmath package.

Comment: Well the first thing that leaps out at me is you do not need to use `$ ... $` within an `eqnarray*` environment. Also, is there any reason you're using `\_`? This will produce an _ character, rather than the subscript that I presume you want? Also `\mathbf` is not a switch, you want `\mathbf{x}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eqnarray` is already math so you should not have `$` but (a) eqnarray should not be used, `amsmath` provides `align` and (b) there is no alignment here at all so you just want `\[`

[image]

```
\[
\underset{\mathbf{S}}{\operatorname{arg\,min}}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in S_i} \| 
\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}_i \|^2
\]
```

Note `_` for subscripts not `\_`